# What Maps API other than Google's do you use with GWT?

Tags: ajax, google-maps, gwt, licensing, maps

It seems that licensing terms would prevent us from using Google Maps API in our software. We would prefer to be absolutely free open source and Google Maps API will require commercial license if our software is sold (correct me if I am wrong - I will delete this question then :-).

So the question is if there are alternative map APIs for GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openlayers is free software, http://openlayers.org/; it has a GWT plugin here:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwt-openlayers/

As far as Google's License (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html):

> 10.9 use the Service or Content with any products, systems, or applications
>   for or in connection with:
>
> (a) real time navigation or route
>   guidance, including but not limited to
>   turn-by-turn route guidance that is
>   synchronized to the position of a
>   user's sensor-enabled device; (b) any
>   systems or functions for automatic or
>   autonomous control of vehicle
>   behavior; or (c) dispatch, fleet
>   management, business asset tracking,
>   or similar enterprise applications
>   (the Google Maps APIs can be used to
>   track assets (such as cars, buses or
>   other vehicles) as long as the
>   tracking application is made available
>   to the public without charge. For
>   example, you may offer a free, public
>   Maps API Implementation that displays
>   real-time public transit or other
>   transportation status information.
>   **If your Maps API Implementation is deployed internally or you are
>   charging for use of your Maps API
>   Implementation, please contact the
>   Google Maps API Premier sales team for
>   more information);**

My advice would be to contact Google and ask them about your specific set of circumstances.  I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for full open data you might want to check out [OpenStreetMap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org) they list in their [FAQ](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FAQ#You_seem_to_have_a_lot_of_existing_map_data._Where_did_it_come_from.3F) where they pull their open data from.

Comment: There isn't anything preventing them from being used with GWT, but there isn't a GWT plugin like with OpenLayers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but a quick google found [GWT-Ext](http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo-maps/#multipleMaps), where it looks like they're using OpenStreetMap data which is free to use in a commercial application.

Comment: Yes, Alan, thank you. I found this too but I would like to know if people indeed use something else...

Comment: this is interesting discussion (sometimes too personal unfortunately) on GWT-Ext: http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_frm/thread/d2a65b4ac8984dad?hl=en